# Correct diacritics in a mysql dump on CentOS

Tags: mysql, locale

On my CentOS server, I have got a dump file of a mysql table which contains special czech characters in it (e.g. á, é, č, ž). When I view the file using cat, the special characters are broken (e.g. ĂĄ instead of á).

I need to correct those characters in the dump and then import it back to the database.

I have tried a few different ways already, but non of them worked, including:

- substitute the characters using sed with the following expression - `cat c_schools | sed 's/ĂĄ/á/g' > c_schools` - but I get an `unterminated s command` error,
- open the file in VIM and fix it manually, but VIM won't let me type the check characters,
- open the file in NANO and fix it manually, but NANO seems to be unable to work with the file at all (the text changes even as I move with the cursor).

---

As suggested in a comment, I opened the file in VIM again and try the following commands:

- `set encoding=utf-8` (this one had no effect at all),
- `set termencoding=iso8859-2` (the output is much better after this one but some characters are still incorrectly displayed, such as ? instead of č, ě or š),
- `:set fileencoding` (outputs `fileencoding=utf-8`)

---

When I copy the file to my Windows machine over FTP and open it in my standard text editor (Notepad++), it is displayed correctly and the encoding used is UTF-8, without BOM.

Comment: Is it a problem in mysqldump or your terminal not showing  the characters correctly?

Comment: The problem is in fact that my Wordpress application misunderstands the data (see [another question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16358312/1103412)). I was hoping that perhaps the data is corrupted in the database and that I could fix it manually and then import it back.

Comment: Copy the dump to your own machine and check it's encoding, so we could exclude the wrong terminal character set on the server.

Comment: I have already done that (as noted at the end of the question) and indeed it is displayed correctly. Does that prove for sure that the data in the database are correct and that the problem lies in the Wordpress application?

Comment: > "Does that prove that the problem lies in the Wordpress application?" Yes

Answer (score 2):

That looks like Unicode (UTF-8) data displayed as ISO-8859-2. There are essentially two possibilities:

1. Your terminal uses ISO-8859-2 as output character set. Then the data itself is probably encoded correctly but displayed incorrectly: What you see is the result that is expected when you display UTF-8 data as if it were ISO-8859-2. Try a terminal and/or an editor that is capable of working with UTF-8. (I'm not sure about nano, but vim *is* able to work with UTF-8 if you use `set encoding=utf-8`.)
2. Your terminal uses UTF-8 as output character set. Then the data itself is encoded incorrectly: It's data that has been "converted" from ISO-8859-2 to UTF-8 even though it was already UTF-8 data. You can use `iconv` or `recode` to translate UTF-8 back to ISO-8859-2 (or rather, "doubly encoded UTF-8" back to proper UTF-8), e.g., by `iconv -f UTF8 -t ISO_8859-2 yourinputfile`.

What terminal program do you use and what's the output of `echo $LC_CTYPE`?

Comment: The output of echo $SHELL is /bin/bash. The output of echo $LC_CTYPE is an empty line.

Comment: The fact that the file is displayed correctly in Notepad and that LC_CTYPE is unset seems to indicate that it's really a display problem (i.e., case 1 in my original answer), rather than an encoding problem (case 2).

Comment: What's your terminal program? Do you use the console (without X11), or do you use any windowing system? In the second case, do you use xterm, rxvt, konsole, gnome terminal, or what other terminal emulator? It is possible to some extent to use UTF-8 on the Linux console, but the support is limited. Most current terminal emulators are able (or can be configured) to work with UTF-8. Search for "unicode" and either "linux console" or the name of your terminal emulator program.